# Typescript Error : Module '".../node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'SubscriptionLike'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ionic3

basically i was trying to build a app that send http request to server and display the data on the app.i was following this [tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/59924f9080aca768e4d2b12e/ionic-3-consuming-rest-api-using-new-angular-43-httpclient).i did the steps show there.but after installing all the modules i got bellow exception.i have little knowledge on ionic.So give me a essay and descriptive solution.

[image]

**packages.json**

```
 {
  "name": "CompassApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^1.11.1",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Rect.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/*
  Generated class for the RestProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {

  apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
  }

  getUsers() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/users').subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @sriharsha_bhat those actually not solving my problem thats why im posting it again

Comment: @ivaro18 there is no solution on preview post.so why you flag it as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Angular 6 does not work with RxJS 5.5 but with RxJS 6.

Your package.json should contain `"rxjs": "^6.1.0"`

Comment: how to install that version as i see https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs/v/5.5.11 5.5.11 is the latest

Comment: it seems not having been updated : see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/releases. You could `npm i rxjs@6`

Comment: not working i install the latest version

Comment: Returing Typescript Error
Module '"E:/AndroidProject/CompassApp/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'

Comment: Use following lines for Observable import : import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Comment: where should i import that

Comment: in your files that caused the error, if it's a library, then update it to be compatible with RxJS 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172409/discussion-between-moin-khan-and-youkouleley).